# Cannot exit loop, run program successfully

Tags: random, while-loop, switch-statement

I'm working on a programming assignment for C, and the program runs, but it doesn't seem to be executing the loop. The purpose of the program is to use a random number generator to get the variables, use a switch statement to determine the volume of the balloon, and then figure out how many balloons it will take to fill the pool. However, when I run it it just sits there as if it's waiting for input, or that it cannot exit the loop. The program is supposed to be run in batch mode. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

```
     #include <stdio.h>
     #include <math.h>
     #include <stdlib.h>
     #include <time.h>
     #define Gravity 32 //feet per second^2 and gravitational accelleration
     #define PI 3.14159
     #define BAL_HEIGHT 12 //balcony height in feet
     #define POOL_CENTER 35 //distance to the center of the pool in feet
     #define thetaMin 5 //degrees
     #define thetaMax 85 //degrees
     #define velocityMin 1 //foot per second
     #define velocityMax 30 //feet per second
     #define heightMin 4.5 //feet
     #define heightMax 7.0 //feet
     #define minDiameter 3 //inches
     #define maxDiameter 9 //inches
     #define Capacity 7 // pool capacity in gallons

    int main ()

    {  


    //inputs theta, velocity, height, diameter, balloons, volume, and capacity
    //in degrees
    //in feet per second
    //of the thrower //for rand max/min
    double currentCapacity = 0; //set beginning capacity to zero
    double volume;
    double volumeTotal = 0;
    int    diameter;
    int    balloonsThrown = 0;
    int    balloonsHit = 0;  //set beginning balloons thrown and hit to zero   

    srand(time(NULL)); //seed sit using time


    while (volumeTotal <= Capacity) 
    {

  double theta = (double) rand()/RAND_MAX * (thetaMax - thetaMin +1) + thetaMin; 

  double velocity = (double) rand()/RAND_MAX * (velocityMin - velocityMax +1) + velocityMin;

  double height = (double) rand()/RAND_MAX * (heightMin - heightMax +1) + heightMin;

  int diameter = rand() % (maxDiameter - minDiameter + 1) + minDiameter;

  int balloonsThrown = rand() % (RAND_MAX);



  switch (diameter) // get diameter from rand equation
  {
     case 3:
        volume == 0.1;//gallons
        break;
     case 4:
        volume == 0.2;
        break;
     case 5:
        volume == 0.3;
        break;
     case 6:  
        volume == 0.55;
        break;
     case 7:  
        volume == 0.8;
        break;
     case 8:  
        volume == 1.25;
        break;
     case 9:  
        volume == 1.7;
        break;   
  } 



  // compute distance 
  double LAUNCH_HEIGHT = BAL_HEIGHT + height; //the sum of the input height and the balcony height

  double radians = theta*(PI/180); //convert angle theta into radians

  double part1 = (velocity*(cos(radians))/Gravity); //first part of the velocity equation

  double part2 = velocity*(sin(radians)); //second part of velocity equation

  double part3 = pow(velocity*(sin(radians)),2);//exponential part of the velocity equation

  double part4 = 2*(Gravity*LAUNCH_HEIGHT);

  double distance = part1*(part2 + sqrt(part3+part4)); //full distance function        


   //determine whether or not the balloon will fill the pool
   //increment the amount of balloons thrown and that hit the pool





  if (distance <= POOL_CENTER -1 && POOL_CENTER +1 >= distance);
  {  // distance is in the range of 34-36 (Pool Center +- 1)
     (currentCapacity += volumeTotal);
  }   

  if (distance > 0);
  {
     (balloonsThrown ++);
  }

  //determining whether to add the balloon to the hit total 

  if (distance > POOL_CENTER -1 && distance < POOL_CENTER +1) 
  {
     (balloonsHit ++);
  }


    }




     double balloonPercentage = (balloonsHit/balloonsThrown);

     printf ("%d balloons hit the pool.\n", balloonsHit);
     printf ("%d balloons were thrown\n", balloonsThrown);
     printf ("%2f%% of balloons hit the pool\n", balloonPercentage);


     return 0; 
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
while (volumeTotal <= Capacity)
```

You never change the value of `volumeTotal`, so this always evaluates to `0.0 <= 7` which is true and the loop continues.

Answer (score 0):

while (volumeTotal <= Capacity) 
 is almost an infinite loop,i guess this is what is causing the issue since your condition is always true and doesnt break.

also i think u can include a default case in switch